# HttpWebResponse in Thread throws Forbidden

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I would like to call multiple times to a web resource, however I get forbidden when asking the webresponse.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Thread[] tt = new Thread[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {            
            Thread t = new Thread(doJob);
            tt[i] = t;
            t.Start();
        }

        foreach (Thread t in tt)
        {
            t.Join();
        }
        Response.Write("TOTAL" + howmanyDone);
    }

    private void doJob()
    {        
        HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");        
        WebResponse res = wr.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than 'i get forbidden'.  What is the full exception?  Does every thread do this or just some?

Comment: Try a different domain than google.com since they probably have the best gear in the world to detect repeated requests (as in possible attacks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a default limit of 2 simultaneous requests to the same domain built
into the framework. Just put this line of code into your code after
you've created the HttpWebRequest object:

```
wr.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 50;
```

Check out the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd5csyhf.aspx